# getting one day timestamp in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-5.5, stored-procedures

Please consider the following stored procedure I have:

**ORIGINAL Stored Procedure:**

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `myProc`()
BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION,SQLWARNING

BEGIN
  -- ERROR
ROLLBACK;

END;

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO mydb.mytable(some values)

SELECT (some values)

FROM   mydb.mytable

WHERE m_dt BETWEEN  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60;

DELETE FROM   mydb.mytable

WHERE m_dt BETWEEN  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60;

COMMIT;

END
```

Since `m_dt` datatype is `datetime`, I want to modify my `BETWEEN` condition. I want to add `00:00:00`  before the `AND` and `23:59:59` after the `AND` condition. For example something like the following:

`WHERE m_dt BETWEEN  CURDATE()  - INTERVAL 60 DAY 00:00:00 AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 23:59:59;`

By any chance it is possible in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would code as follows:

```
SELECT (some values)
FROM   mydb.mytable
WHERE m_dt >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY + INTERVAL     0 SECOND 
AND   m_dt <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY + INTERVAL 86399 SECOND;

DELETE FROM mydb.mytable
WHERE m_dt >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY + INTERVAL     0 SECOND 
AND   m_dt <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY + INTERVAL 86399 SECOND;
```

Just to demonstrate the date math,

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> NOW() now,CURDATE() + INTERVAL 0 SECOND dt0,
    -> CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY + INTERVAL     0 SECOND dt1,
    -> CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY + INTERVAL 86399 SECOND dt2\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
now: 2014-07-14 18:18:21
dt0: 2014-07-14 00:00:00
dt1: 2014-05-15 00:00:00
dt2: 2014-05-15 23:59:59
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Just make sire `m_dt` is indexed.

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Awesome. This solution is much better than the other. I believe performance wise it's wise not to use `BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

I believe the first part already evaluates to 00:00:00. So I just added the seconds in.

```
WHERE m_dt BETWEEN  (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND 
  (DATE_ADD((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY),INTERVAL 86399 SECOND))
```